# How to acces elements of a vector which contains pointers to strings?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm learning about vectors and have come across a problem that challenges to create a vector of items using pointers to strings

```
vector<string*> items;
```

I am trying to add items by passing the list via reference to the function below:

```
void add_item(vector<string*> &items) {
  string thing;

  cout << "Add this item: ";
  cin  >> thing;

  string* ptr = &thing;

  items.push_back(ptr);

  return;
}
```

and then displaying all the items using:

```
void display(vector<string*> items) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= items.size(); i++) {
        cout << "> " << *items[i] << "\n"; 
    }

    return;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, there is no output on the screen and then the program randomly terminates. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Chances are you don't want a vector of pointers to strings. You probably want a vector of strings. Unless you are utilizing some polymorphic objects, you don't want a vector of pointers of any kind.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's my bad, I accidentally did that when I was typing my question. Have just made the edit.

Comment: @Ron That is what I thought as well, but that's what the question suggests

Comment: @dankpenny On a side note, your `display()` loop is going out of bounds of the `vector`.  It needs to use `<` instead of `<=`, and it should be using `vector<string*>::size_type` (which is usually `size_t`) instead of `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `add_item()` function, `thing` is a **local variable**. You are pushing its address into the vector, but when the function returns then `thing` no longer exists, so the pointer stored in your vector is invalid, and attempting to dereference it later will cause undefined behavior.

As mentioned in the comments, what you most likely want is a vector of `string` *objects*, rather than `string` *pointers*.

However, if you *really* need to use a `vector<string*>` (although I don't see the need, and it is not something I would recommend), then you should create a new string in your `add_item()` function (and, of course, then `delete` it when you later remove it from the vector):

```cpp
void add_item(vector<string*> &items) {
  string *thing = new string;
  cout << "Add this item: ";
  cin  >> *thing;
  items.push_back(thing);
  return;
}
```

```cpp
vector<string*> items;
add_item(items);
...
for (size_t i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
    delete items[i]; 
}
```

In this case, the `thing` is created on the *heap* and will remain valid after the function has returned.

Comment: When showing examples with owning bare pointers, I would warn about memory leaks, double-free crashes, exception safety, etc.

Comment: @eerorika Fair point! I *did* mention the need to `delete` but maybe a bit more? I'll give it some thought.

Comment: If you are going to store pointers like this, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` instead, then you don't have to worry about calling `delete` manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice edit - thanks for that! I considered an example using `unique_ptr` but OP *seemed* to want to use raw pointers (at least, that's how I understood the question).

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a pointer to string `thing` to the vector of pointers to strings. But as soon as `add_item` returns, `thing` goes out of scope. So the pointer you added is now a pointer to nothing.

Why do you need a vector of pointers? That's almost never right.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as saying vector of pointer is almost never right. It's uncommon, sure. A pointer to a `std::string` however. I can't remember ever having a need for that.

Answer (score 1):

> How to acces elements of a vector which contains pointers to strings?

Like this:

```
*items[i]
```

---

However, the pointer in the vector must point to a valid object or else the behaviour of accessing the object through the pointer is undefined.

In your example, the string is an automatic variable in `add_item`. When the function returns, all automatic variables including the string are automatically destroyed. At this point the pointer in the vector has become invalid. The behaviour of indirecting through the pointer and accessing the object is undefined.

> What am I doing wrong here?

You attempt to access through invalid pointer and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

Here is a correct example using a vector of pointers:

```
{
    std::string thing = "example";
    items.push_back(&thing);
    display(items);
    items.pop_back();  // erase the pointer that is about to be invalidated
}
// the string no longer exists here
```

Notice how the string still exists when it is being displayed.

But, you probably should be using `std::vector<std::string>` instead in order to avoid problems such as this.